# Why does Typescript run the abstract class first?

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I'm getting a hard time trying to solve my abstract class issue with Typescript. First of all, let me know what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a class called `Sword` which extends `Weapon`. Each `Weapon` has to have some properties such as `damage`, but since each item has a different damage type (e.g Sword may do 1 damage, a bow may do 2 damage) I have to define specific properties in the `Sword` class. My script looks like this:

```
abstract class Weapon
{
    protected abstract damage: number;
    constructor() {
        alert(this.damage);
    }

    showDamage() {
        alert(this.damage);
    }
}

class Sword extends Weapon implements WeaponInterface {
    protected damage: number = 999;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const sword = new Sword;
sword.showDamage();
```

Running the script above at `http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/`, I get two messages:

```
undefined
999
```

I'm not exactly sure why `Weapon.constructor` runs first, because as long as `Weapon.constructor` runs first, there is literally no point in declaring an abstract value. For example, I have to do something like `super(this.damage)` in order to pass it into `Weapon` class. I won't need the `protected abstract damage` if I do so.

If I cannot even create a very basic inheritence with `Typescript`, why does it even support abstract classes at all? I'll have to do `new Weapon(new Sword)` which means I cannot typehint `SwordInterface` on other classes like `Inventory`.

```
class Inventory
{
    // Let's assume we have a "Shield" equipped so we can only equip "Sword" type
    addSword(sword: SwordInterface): void {

    }
}
```

I'm not very experienced with compiled languages and Typescript. Could anybody tell me what would be the proper way to achieve this? Passing class properties into `super()` call sounds lame...

I don't want to break my inheritence and interfaces either.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1617#issuecomment-69215655

Comment: You would have this with any other language: you're accessing, from the base constructor, a value that is only initialized later, by the subclass constructor. So it's undefined. Accessing overridable members from a constructor is a bad idea. Don't do that. I don't understand what the problem is with passing the damage using super(damage). This would work fine. I also don't understand why you need to access the damage from the base constructor: surely the alert is not part of your real code.

Comment: @JBNizet Because each weapon can have plently of parameters. Damage, accuracy, crit chance, crit damage etc. I don't want to pass every single of them.

Comment: But why do you have to access them from the base class constructor?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Otherwise I'll need to do something like `new Sword().constructProperties()` in order to properly construct it. It doesn't look pretty.

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. As your own example shows, accessing the damage from a method works as you expect it to work. The problem is accessing it from the base class constructor. And you've still not said why you wanted to do that.

Comment: Well... to construct properties? Let me show you a real world example from my open source repo: https://github.com/Aristona/Phaser.Adventure-Capitalist/blob/master/src/Shop/Shop.ts#L59. In this line, I'm reading the `index` value of a `Shop`, then I make a calculation based on it and construct a property called `position`, which is a `x,y` location of the `Shop` on the GUI. All the shared data is located in the abstract class to prevent duplications. If I move it out of constructor, it will be like `new LemonShop().positionIt().doOtherStuff()` just to `construct` the shop.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. But if you need to do `new Sword().constructProperties()`, and just want to do `new Sword()` then call `this.constructProperties()` at the end of your Sword constructor.

Comment: That's a better idea than passing multiple parameters into `super`. What if I don't want to add `this.constructProperties()` on each `Item`? Can I force it to call `constructProperties` after `construct` takes place, like by relying on DI containers and alike? It could be magic, as long as there is a way. I can accept it as the answer if you write it as an answer, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript does not treat property initialization in the class body in any special way - it's done as part of that class constructor. It's possible to imagine a language that will apply this assignment

```
class Sword extends Weapon implements WeaponInterface {
    protected damage: number = 999;
```

very early, before any constructor is run. Typescript does not do that probably because it's not the simplest and most consistent thing to do.

So you have to do it yourself. One way to achieve what you want is to split code in your constructors into two parts, one that initializes the variables, and the other one that does the rest. Then you can manage yourself when each part is called. This technique is sometimes called [two-phase initialization](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2008/08/19/two-phase-initialization/):

```
abstract class Weapon
{
    protected abstract damage: number;

    // NOTE: abstract properties must be initialized by subclasses
    //     in initialize() because they are used here in Weapon class constructor
    protected initialize(): void { }

    constructor() {
        this.initialize();
        alert(this.damage);
    }

    showDamage() {
        alert(this.damage);
    }
}

class Sword extends Weapon  {
    protected damage: number;

    protected initialize(): void {
        super.initialize();
        this.damage = 999;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const sword = new Sword;
sword.showDamage(); // shows 999 twice
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course base class constructors run first. What would the alternative be?

```
class Base {
  damage = 12;
}

class Derived extends Base {
  constructor() {
    // This should print 'undefined' ?
    console.log(this.damage);
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay... How would you design the `Sword-Weapon-Item` inheritence? The `Weapon` needs to access `Sword`'s properties in order to calculate damage. (access the base damage, roll the crit chance, if it rolls crit, multiply the damage with crit damage). `new Item(new Weapon(new Sword()))`? That looks weird...

Comment: If gravity always makes things fall, how am I supposed to fly? It's hard work. But it doesn't change the direction of things.

Comment: If gravity always makes things fall, then it is most likely immutable. However, it isn't since each `Planet` has a different gravity level. In this case, you should be able to pass a specific gravity level. (or even better, your `Planet` knows/calculates it's gravity without you passing) If gravity force is pretty low, maybe you can fly.

Answer (score 1):

The base c'tor is run before the assignment of `damage`. Take a look at the generated constructor of `Sword`:

```
function Sword() {
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
    _this.damage = 999;
    return _this;
}
```

As an alternative you could pass the damage as base c'tor parameter:

```
abstract class Weapon {

    protected damage: number;

    constructor(damage: number) {
        this.damage = damage;
        alert(this.damage);
    }

    showDamage() { /*...*/ }
}

class Sword extends Weapon  {

    constructor() {
        super(999);
    }
}
```

Or shorter:

```
abstract class Weapon {
    constructor(protected damage: number) {
        alert(this.damage);
    }

    showDamage() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look good when your `Sword` class has multiple parameters. Also, duplicating code is a terrible thing. With this approach, whenever I add a new property into my `Sword` class, I also have to make sure to pass it into `super()`. Then I have to modify `Weapon.constructor()` to accept that `parameter`, assign it as a local propery. I just don't think this is a good approach.

Comment: Using "parameter properties" you can remove the duplication within the base class. (I've appended it to my answer.)